# Changes not being reflected on new server

Tags: mysql, migration, wp-config, server, configuration

I'm migrating a wordpress site from one server to another. I just finished setting up NGIX, PHP, MySQL, etc... however I still haven't restored the old DB on this new server. I can see the site goes up, but it takes me to the "wp-admin/install.php" page. Isn't this configuration supposed to stored within the Wordpress files I copied? or will it set up properly once I restore the old DB?

Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is stored in the database. Without the old database, it is expected that WordPress thinks that its a new installation. Don't worry about it. Once you have migrated your old database properly, things will run as normal